# Not getting the expected output while echoing

Tags: windows, batch, script, batch-file

I have written the following batch script to echo the path of a folder.

```
set TW_prod_cer_path=D:\prod_path 
set /p client="Enter client: " 

    if %client% equ TW (  
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set prod_path=!client!_prod_cer_path
        echo !prod_path!
        echo %!prod_path!%
    )
```

And I am getting the below output

```
Enter client: TW
TW_prod_cer_path
ECHO is off.
```

But my expected output is:

```
Enter client: TW
TW_prod_cer_path
D:\prod_path
```

Could someone explain the reason for this and also the corrective action to be taken to get the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem here is that *non*-delayed expansion – the `%…%` – is done for the entire `if` statement including its whole bracketed block. (It's a parser trick; cmd still considers the whole thing a single command line.)

In other words, `%…%` expansions here happen *before* the `set` command is reached, despite it being above.

The second problem is that you got the delayed/non-delayed expansion ordering wrong. If you want to "dereference" a variable, you would need its name to be expanded not later but *earlier;* e.g.

```
set foo=value
set bar=foo
echo !%bar%!
```

---

Have you considered another programming language, such as PowerShell? It has hashtables:

```
$prod_paths = @{
    "TW" = "D:\prod_path";
}
$client = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter client"
if ($client -ceq "TW") {
    echo $prod_paths.Item($client)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When `if` command is parsed, the parser sees

```
echo %!prod_path!%
```

and here there is a problem: normal expansion (`%var%`) is executed before delayed expansion (`!var!`) so this code tries to retrieve the content of a variable when the name of the variable is still not defined.

Of course the inverse syntax will also not work

```
echo !%prod_path%!
```

In this case the name of the variable is evaluated at parse time, but at parse time the variable still has not value so when delayed expansion occur, there is not a variable name to read.

You need a double delayed expansion, that is you need something like

```
echo !!prod_path!!
```

But this is not a valid syntax.

So, we need to use delayed expansion to retrieve the name of the variable that we need to read, and then delayed expansion to retrieve the value inside the variable.

The simplest solution is to change the code structure to avoid the problem (`call` a subrotine, use `goto`, ...), but there is another alternative.

```
for %%a in (!prod_path!) do echo !%%a!
```

Retrieve the name of the variable (first delayed expansion), store the retrieved value inside a `for` replaceable parameter and then read the value in the variable being referenced by the replaceable parameter (second delayed expansion)